# Magento 2 Docker: Frontend ignore updated files

Tags: magento2, docker

i'm losing my mind and work.

This is not my first Docker expierience, I worked with magento-docker in the past.

Today I have this strange problem that cannot resolve by myself and seem no other had.

When I save a file  on vendor or app/design folder Magento completely ignore the update.
I am sure that this files in the container (bin/magento-docker bash) are up to date immediately on save. It seems like the web server don't take this files.

bin/magento cache:clean/flush do not resolve, I had to stop and restart docker

The containers are create with ece-tools build:compose with --no-varnish option

Comment: This could be because you have generated static files. If you are in production mode you can use the command bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy to regenerate them. If you are in developper mode you can clear your static folder or you can launch a setup:upgrade which will delete all kind of cache and your static folder.

Comment: Thank you for you time Carlo.
I think the problem was varnish. With all the test I make I forget varnish in the containers. Varnish was disabled in Magento, but the tls container read from varnish (https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-containers-service.html - Ports: 443 (default), 8080:80 (Varnish bypass)). I tried to change port like said in the doc and got an error for 80 used port. So I disabled varnish again with no-varnish, and now seems fine.